# sporadic Error during Trimming of object Properties using Auto Mapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, automapper

```
public class Trimmer<TModel>
    {
       public Trimmer()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(c =>
            {
                c.CreateMap<string, string>().ConvertUsing(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? s : s.Trim());
                c.CreateMap<TModel, TModel>();
            });
        }

       /// <summary>
       /// Function take List of object of type TModel what supplied during initalization and applied trim on every property which is string.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="models">An model object of type TModel</param>
       /// <returns>List of objects of type TModel with string properties that are trimmed (leading and trailing spaces removed)</returns>
       public List<TModel> StringTrimmer(List<TModel> models)
       {
           if (models == null)
           {
               return null;               
           }
           var modelList = models.Select(StringTrimmer).ToList();
           return modelList;
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Function take object of type T which one supply during Initalization and applied trim on every property which is string.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="model">An model object of Type TModel</param>
       /// <returns>Object of type TModel with string properties that are trimmed (leading and trailing spaces removed)</returns>
        public TModel StringTrimmer(TModel model)
        {
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();`enter code here`
            var mappedObj = Mapper.Map<TModel,TModel>(model);
            return mappedObj;
        }
```

I created a Generic class called Trimmer with overloaded methods called StringTrimmer. Intend of the methods is to trim any space for Tmodel object properties using Automapper. It worked fine but then sometime these method I got following error:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type.

When it should not be happening as I am converting same object type to same object type.

Comment: What is the TModel that is causing this error?

Comment: TModel is just generic type. In my case its just the class name whose object properties I want to trim. For example if I have a class "Deck" then I will make "var obj = new  Trimmer<Deck>()".

Comment: @TimothyGhanem I did found the problem and Answer the question as why I was getting the errors sporadically. It was one of the many possible testCases where the code will give me error. Solution is to move the Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); inside Mapper.Initialize

Answer (score 0):

```
Code
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using AutoMapper;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
public class Data
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
public class DataDto
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string No { get; set; }
}
public class ObjectModifier<TModel>
{
    public ObjectModifier()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(c =>
        {
            c.CreateMap<string, string>().ConvertUsing(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? s : s.Trim());
            c.CreateMap<TModel, TModel>();
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        });
    }

    public TModel StringTrimmer(TModel model)
    {
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        var mappedObj = Mapper.Map<TModel, TModel>(model);
        return mappedObj;
    }
}

public static class ObjectConverter
{
    public static T2 ToObject<T1, T2>(T1 val)
    {
        return Mapper.DynamicMap<T1, T2>(val);
    }
}

class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = new Data()
        {
            FirstName = "Foo ",
            LastName = "ooF"
        };
        ObjectModifier<Data> objMod = new ObjectModifier<Data>();
        var result = objMod.StringTrimmer(doc);  //Good 
        var result2 = ObjectConverter.ToObject<Data, DataDto>(doc);  //Good
        var result3 = objMod.StringTrimmer(doc);   //Error
    }
}
```

}

@TimothyGhanem I found the problem its because I am using Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); at the start of StringTrimmer when it should be after the CreateMap in Mapper.Initialize. As per why its working sporadically

1. Case
   As per Below code. when main Method calls ObjectModifier class to trim space fron Data Class properties Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() will find mapping Data to Data which means same properties in the source and destination for the Map thus get pass Validation.
2. Case
   Now In Next Line We use a new Map which is mentioned in ObjectConverter and convert Data to Datadto works fine.
3. Case
   Now in next line again trying to trim using StringTrimmer but now when execution comes to Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() it will not be valid as the Mapper hold the context of previous Map which is from the ObjectConverter and now Data and Datadto has some properties which are not actually same like "lastName" in Data is "no" in Datadto. Thus Fails. This is a one of the case I came up with and it fits some explanation I am seeking for sporadically failure.

Thanks